# Find out whether a user has association bonus

Tags: support, feature-request, reputation, oauth2

I searched for this in the api docs and on this page but couldn't find any information:

I have an api token of a given user. **Is there a way to find out whether this user has association bonus rights?**

I know that I could just look whether a user has more than 200 rep on any site but this is error prone because one can also have the association bonus with less reputation when you lost it again.

Comment: MEE, please run this test for me.  On *Security* you have only one rep but do have the association bonus.  Please edit [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/7270/52483), if you can, to fix the formatting.  Please let me know when you've made the attempt.  There's some conflicting behavior/information at play here.

Comment: @BrocAdams. I have only one rep due to a bounty. It shows the “needs be reviewed” warning when loading the editor. Have not tried to submit the edit yet, though. (So no insta-edit rights)

Comment: Yes, I knew that was why you had the rep, and why I wanted to see if you could edit.  The decree was that you would be able to, but the API suggested otherwise.  Sorting it out and will answer this Q later (in between RL) if no one beats me to it.

Comment: Mee, are you able to upvote a post on Security?

Comment: @BrockAdams nope. It submits the anonymous feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can find out if the user has received the association bonus using the API.  It's a bit clunky though.

However, as we discovered, ["association bonus rights"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) are rather meaningless at the moment.  Otherwise, you'd be able to edit wikis, upvote, comment, and flag on [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com) right now, despite currently only having 1 rep there.

If the association "rights" persisted, then you could use [the API's `/users/{id}/privileges` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges-on-users#pagesize=100&id=169072&filter=!9Z(-x-Q)8&site=security&run=true) to see if you had, say, [the *Edit Community Wiki* privilege](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) despite not having 100 rep.

However, they currently do not stick, and I've created [a bug report on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322316/the-association-bonus-does-persist-as-advertised-and-altruistic-users-are-pena) which you might want to review (and upvote).

#### Using the `/users/{ids}/reputation-history` route to see if the association bonus was given:

The [`/users/{ids}/reputation-history` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history) will show if the user has received the `association_bonus`. Example:
    [/reputation-history#ids=169072&site=security](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history#ids=169072&filter=!9Z(-x-Q)8&site=security&run=true)

Unfortunately, a user may have thousands of reputation events, and there is no way to filter, nor change the sorting of, that route's output.

Fortunately:

1. Although the order can't be changed, the results do appear to be sorted by `creation_date`.
2. In most cases, the user will get the bonus within the first 200, or so, events.

So, **a recipe for seeing if the user has the bonus might go like this:**

1. Get the user's total number of events like:
     [/2.2/users/331508/reputation-history?site=stackoverflow&filter=!--pn9sU*3FRx](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history#ids=331508&filter=!--pn9sU*3FRx&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   Result:  `... "total": 7192`
2. Divide the total by 100 and add 1 to get the number of pages.  In this case, 72.
3. Fetch the *last* page like:
     [/2.2/users/331508/reputation-history?page=72&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-x-d4A](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history#page=72&pagesize=100&ids=331508&filter=!9Z(-x-d4A&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   Result:  entry not yet present.
4. If the results do not contain the `association_bonus` entry fetch the penultimate page:
     [/2.2/users/331508/reputation-history?page=71&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-x-d4A](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history#page=71&pagesize=100&ids=331508&filter=!9Z(-x-d4A&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

   Result:  `association_bonus` entry found.
5. The `association_bonus` entry will almost always be there.  If not, continue fetching pages off the end until you are satisfied.

---

Notes:

1. The `/users/{ids}/reputation` route won't work because it only reports (some) rep changes associated with posts.
2. There is [no easy way to detect the bonus in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293000/determine-if-a-user-got-an-association-bonus-in-sede).